# Fitting a zero inflated poisson distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

I have a vector of count data that is strongly over dispersed and zero inflated.

The vector looks like this:

```
i.vec=c(0,63,1,4,1,44,2,2,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,11,1,1,0,0,0,2)
m=mean(i.vec)
# 3.040816
sig=sd(i.vec)
# 10.86078
```

I would like to fit a distribution to this, which I strongly suspect will be a zero inflated poisson (ZIP).  But I need to perform a significance test to demonstrate that a ZIP distribution fits the data.

If I had a normal distribution, I could do a chi square goodness of fit test using the function goodfit() in the package vcd, but I don't know of any tests that I can perform for zero inflated data.

Comment: belongs on stats.stackexchange.com maybe?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
# LOAD LIBRARIES
library(fitdistrplus)    # fits distributions using maximum likelihood
library(gamlss)          # defines pdf, cdf of ZIP


# FIT DISTRIBUTION (mu = mean of poisson, sigma = P(X = 0)
fit_zip = fitdist(i.vec, 'ZIP', start = list(mu = 2, sigma = 0.5))

# VISUALIZE TEST AND COMPUTE GOODNESS OF FIT    
plot(fit_zip)
gofstat(fit_zip, print.test = T)
```

Based on this, it does not look like ZIP is a good fit.

Comment: +1 ; But it does look reasonably acceptable with a negative binomial fit: fit_zip2 <- fitdist(i.vec, 'nbinom', start = list(mu = 3, size = 0.1))

Comment: it does look good. i would also try the zero-inflated negative binomial distribution which is available as `zinegbin` in the `VGAM` package.

Comment: Thank you so much!  How did you select your mu and sigma?

Comment: Also, did you mean to write "print.test=T"?

Comment: they are just starting values for the optimization algorithm which i filled arbitrarily. instead you can use `mu = mean(i.vec[i.vec > 0])` and `p` equal to the proportion of zeros in your sample as a starting point. and yes i mean to write `print.test = T`